# Are my three solutions for part (iii),(iv),and (v) correct? The question is below

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

4.2 Consider the following predicate symbols with which we associate the following meanings:

- $B(x)$ represents " $x$ is a bird"
- $W(x)$ represents " $x$ is a worm"
- $E(x, y)$ represents " $x$ eats $y$ "

Provide a predicate formula for each of the following statements:

(i) "Every bird east every worm"

(ii) "Some birds do not eat some worms"

(iii) "No bird is eaten by a worm"

(iv) "Some worms do not get eaten by birds"

(v) "Worms are only eaten by birds"

For part (iii) their solution is:

$\neg \exists x \exists y(B(x) \wedge W(y) \wedge E(y, x))$

But my solution is:

$\forall x\forall y(B(x) \wedge W(y) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x))$

For part (iv) their solution is:

$\exists x(W(x) \wedge \forall y(B(y) \rightarrow \neg E(y, x)))$

But my solution is:

$\forall y \exists x(B(y) \wedge W(x) \rightarrow \neg  E(y,x))$

For part (v) their solution is:

$\forall x(W(x) \rightarrow \forall y(E(y, x) \rightarrow B(y)))$

But my solution is:

$\forall x \forall y(\neg B(y) \wedge W(x) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x))$

Comment: For (iii) $¬∃x∃y(B(x)∧W(y)∧E(y,x))$, move inside the negation sign to get: $∀x∀y¬(B(x)∧W(y)∧E(y,x))$ and consider that $\lnot (P \land Q)$ is $(P \to \lnot Q)$.

Comment: For (v) move the $\forall y$ outside with [PNF equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication) to get: $∀x∀y(W(x)→(E(y,x)→B(y)))$ and then use Contraposition to get: $∀x∀y(W(x)→(\lnot B(y) \to \lnot E(y,x)))$. Finally, use [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)).

Comment: Thank you so much Mauro.

Comment: For (iv) "Some worms do not get eaten by birds" you have to consider that there are some words (and thus Existential quantifier for Worms) that are not eaten at all by birds (and thus the Universal quantifier for Birds). If you switch the quantifier, what you get is maybe a different worm for every bird.

Comment: I just have when confusion:
$\exists x(W(x) \wedge \forall y(B(y) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x)))$
When I write this formula as PNF is it:
$\exists x \forall y(W(x) \wedge B(y) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x))$
Or:
$\exists x \forall y(W(x) \wedge (B(y) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x)))$

Comment: Correct: your solution for (iv) is simply WRONG...

Answer (score 1):

Your **answer to (iii)** is *logically equivalent* to the given one, indeed :
$$       \begin{eqnarray}[cc]\neg \exists x \exists y(B(x) \wedge W(y) \wedge E(y, x)) & \equiv \\ 
\forall x \neg \exists y(B(x) \wedge W(y) \wedge E(y, x)) & \equiv \\
\forall x \forall y \neg (B(x) \wedge W(y) \wedge E(y, x)) & \equiv \\
\forall x \forall y  \neg \big(B(x) \wedge W(y) \big) \vee \neg E(y, x) & \equiv \\
\forall x\forall y(\big( B(x) \wedge W(y)\big) \rightarrow \neg E(y,x))   \end{eqnarray}$$

Your solution lacks those extra braces.

Your **answer to (iv)** is wrong : what you wrote,

> $\forall y \exists x(B(y) \wedge W(x) \rightarrow \neg  E(y,x))$

Readily means "For every bird there is a worm that does not get eaten by this bird.".

It is possible, however, that the worm(s) that this particular bird failed to eat get swallowed by some other bird that wants its share!

Your **answer to (v)** is once again logically equivalent to the given one, but I'm too lazy to show why.